# Dynamically replace machine learning model in Spark without restarting the Spark-streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I load a machine learning model in memory in Spark and I use it to make classifications on streaming messages. I want to be able to change the model (for example I trained a model with a better accuracy) without restarting the spark job (this would imply that some data will not be classified). Is there a way to dynamically replace the model that is applied on the data?

Thank you!

Comment: does this solve your question? 1. stop stream 2. replace location w/ new pickled model 3. start stream (if you have write ahead logs enabled [checkpoint location] it will pick up the stream where you left off
`df.stop()

df.writeStream.(...).option("checkpointLocation", "...").start()`

Comment: Yes, even though it looks like a workaround I think it would solve the problem. However, I think that the root of the problem lies within the model itself. I think that a better approach would be to use an online machine learning algorithm instead.